# run another animation after running an animation with ccbanimationmanager

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

I'm running cocos2d with cocosbuilder 2.1 and I use the cocosbuilder animation delegate (`CCBAnimationManagerDelegate::completedAnimationSequenceNamed`) to get notified when an animation has completed and take actions like firing another cocosbuilder animation.

It runs fine the first time the `foodfactoryshow` animation is run from the delegate and after the animation is completed it also runs `restoration` animation correctly. However, when `restoration` animation is completed, the parameter `name` for `-(void) completedAnimationSequenceNamed` method is `NULL`!?

```
-(void) completedAnimationSequenceNamed:(NSString*)name
{
if ([name isEqualToString:@"foodfactoryshow"])
{
    [manager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"restoration"];
}
if ([name isEqualToString:@"restoration"])
{
    [self colorLayerChanged];
    self.gameLayer.isLock = true;
}
}
```

Is this a bug or am I not supposed to run animations from the `CCBAnimationManagerDelegate::completedAnimationSequenceNamed` method!?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is a CCBReader bug. There is an open issue about it in the CocosBuilder github page (https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/issues/121). It should be fixed in the latest version of CocosBuilder + CCBReader, however, if you want to use the 2.1 version you can change the "sequenceCompleted" method of CCBAnimationManager to the following:

```
- (void) sequenceCompleted
{
    NSString *completedSequenceName = [runningSequence.name copy];
    int nextSeqId = runningSequence.chainedSequenceId;
    runningSequence = NULL;

    if (nextSeqId != -1)
    {
        [self runAnimationsForSequenceId:nextSeqId tweenDuration:0];
    }

    [delegate completedAnimationSequenceNamed:completedSequenceName];
    [completedSequenceName release];
}
```